# Show that A is dense in M if and only if the following hold:

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, metric-spaces

A is said to be dense in M (or, as some authors say, *everywhere dense*) if $\overline A = M$.

**Question:** How do I show that A is dense in M (that $\overline A = M)$ if and only if any of the following hold:

a) Every point in M is the limit of a sequence from A.

b) $B_\epsilon(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for every $x \in M$ and every $\epsilon > 0$.

c) $U\cap A \neq \emptyset$ for every nonempty open set U.

d) $A^c$ has empty interior.

**This is what I've tried so far:**

a) I know that $x \in \overline A$ if and only if there is a sequence $(x_n) \subset A$ with $x_n \to x$. So if every point $x$ in M is the limit of a sequence from A, that means that every point $x$ in M is in $\overline A$ and thus that $M \subseteq \overline A$. I think that the next step is to show that $\overline A \subseteq M$, but I don't know how.

b) I know that $x \in \overline A$ if and only if $B_\epsilon(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. So if there exists an $\epsilon$ for every $x \in M$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\cap A \neq \emptyset$, I know that every $x \in M$ is in $\overline A$ and that $M \subseteq \overline A$. Again, I think that the next step is showing that $\overline A \subseteq M$ but I don't see how.

c) I didn't get far here. I tried proof by contradiction: assume that $U \cap A = \emptyset$, then there exists a point $x \in M$ with $B_\epsilon(x) \cap A = \emptyset$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. If you can now show that $M\backslash\{x\}$ is still closed that would mean that $\overline A \neq M$ and thus that A is not dense in M, but I'm not sure how to do this.

d) I have no clue really..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a) $\overline A\subseteq M$ trivially - $M$ is the whole space here

Comment: General hint: In order to show multiple equivalences, it may be less work to prove a cyclic implication, for example $\text{dense}\implies \text{a)}\implies \text{b)}\implies \text{c)}\implies \text{d)}\implies \text{dense}$ (or in any order you may find simplre)

Comment: What is your exact definition of closure? It matters for the proof. Many texts define b) or c) to be the definition of closure. And you're obviously working in metric spaces, or a) is even false.

Comment: B is simple once you use the  correction I made.